# Simply send the user to URL based on his SELECT OPTION only when clicking SUBMIT

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a list of  options containing different URL's, and then redirect the user based on his selected option once he clicks on submit.

This works - but it works to fast, as the user doesn't need to click any submit.

```html
<select id="dynamic_select">
  <option value="" selected>Pick a Website</option>
  <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
  <option value="http://www.youtube.com">YouTube</option>
  <option value="https://www.netflix.com">Netflix</option>
</select>

<script>
    $(function(){
      // bind change event to select
      $('#dynamic_select').on('change', function () {
          var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
          if (url) { // require a URL
              window.location = url; // redirect
          }
          return false;
      });
    });
</script>
```

How can I implement a submit button to this code, so the user doesn't get redirected at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, simply by add a `submit` button (via an input) you can just handle the `submit` click then grab the value of the `select` element. This way it will only trigger on the `submit` click and not each change of the `select`

```
<select id="dynamic_select">
    <option value="" selected>Pick a Website</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
    <option value="http://www.youtube.com">YouTube</option>
    <option value="https://www.netflix.com">Netflix</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" id="send_url" value="Submit" />

<script>
    $(function(){
      // bind change event to select
      $('#send_url').on('click', function () {
          var url = $('#dynamic_select').val(); // get selected value
          if (url) { // require a URL
              window.location = url; // redirect
          }
          return false;
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: LOL. So easy, yet so difficult. Your changes did the miracle! :) Thank you so much.

Comment: It's alright! It is usually the most simple of solutions to big problems :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a submit button and put your code on its click(note:before redirect you should check if url is selected):

```
<select id="dynamic_select">
<option value="" selected>Pick a Website</option>
<option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
<option value="http://www.youtube.com">YouTube</option>
<option value="https://www.netflix.com">Netflix</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />

<script>
$(function(){
  // bind change event to select
  $('#submit').on('click', function () {
      var url = $('#dynamic_select').val(); // get selected value
      if (url!="") { // require a URL
          window.location = url; // redirect
      }
      else
         alert('Please select a Website!');
      return false;
  });
});
</script>
```